# MATLAB Bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, redirect, command-line

Let's say I have this MATLAB function

```
function a = testfun(filename)
% do something with file contents and create some variable a
disp(a);
```

I would like to have a shell script that runs on Cygwin as follows:

```
./testscript.sh < inputforfunction.txt > outputoffunction.txt
```

The input file would contain the data I need.
After running this command, the output file will contain the result of running testfun(filename).

Up till now, I can write the output to the file outputoffunction.txt.

**The problem is I want to read the file name "inputforfunction.txt".**

I am able to read in the **file contents** but not the **file name**, any hints please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the file as an **argument** to the bash script?

```
./testscript.sh inputforfunction.txt > outputoffunction.txt
```

In the script you can access `$1` - it will evaluate to `'inputforfunction.txt'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I was aware of this option and unfortunately I'm restrained to redirect both input and output.

Comment: @LyésKhalil - is it possible for you to redirect `echo inputforfunction.txt`?

Comment: Not sure I got what you meant

Comment: @LyésKhalil if you have the file name in bash and you can only pass it using redirection, why don't you `echo` the file name into the stdin of `testscript.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

```
read file_name
./testscript.sh < $file_name > outputoffunction.txt
```